# How I can make this with html and css?

Tags: html, css, psd

I want convert a psd file to html and css and I want to convert it into html and css . But I cant do that

[image]

Comment: No tried yourself?

Comment: once try and then if you stuck some where then we will help you. This is not right way to ask question.

Comment: Unless writing HTML code you can't get it from PhotoShop. But you can get it using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/). Like PhotoShop you draw in your free hand after that just 'Save as' as '.html' file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Add some `@media` queries to make it responsive.

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.breadcrumb {
  padding: 9px 12px 9px 24px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.breadcrumb:first-child {
  padding: 9px 12px 9px 18px !important;
}

.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 101%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  left: 101%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.breadcrumb.active,
.breadcrumb:hover {
  padding: 9px 12px 9px 24px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb .active:before,
.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb:hover:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #3f51b5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb.active:after,
.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb:hover:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #3f51b5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="active breadcrumb">Search</a>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb">Meet</a>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb">Discuss</a>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb">Manage</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code

```css
.breadcrumb li{
  display:inline-block;  
  padding:10px 15px;
  position: relative; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left:-4px;
  background: #eee;
}
.breadcrumb li:first-child{
  background: #054EA3;
}
.breadcrumb li a{
  padding-left: 15px;  
  color:#888;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.breadcrumb li:first-child a{
  color:#fff;
}
.breadcrumb li:after, .breadcrumb li:before {
 left: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.breadcrumb li:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-left-color: #eee;
 border-width: 20px;
 margin-top: -20px;
  z-index:99999;
}
.breadcrumb li:first-child:after {
 border-left-color: #054EA3;
}
.breadcrumb li:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-left-color: #ccc;
 border-width: 21px;
 margin-top: -21px;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MEET</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">DISCUSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MANAGE</a></li>
</ul>
```